# background-repeat: no-repeat won't start repeating

Tags: html, css

this is my stylesheet. Repeat doesn't work. I'm very new to coding and I'm really confused. Please help me. I know it's a very simple code, but it won't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
  background-color: white;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    min-width: 256px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 24px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    background: url("background_image.jpg") 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: you want repeat or no repeat?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon at the end of the `background` element. Adding this (tested in W3Schools TryIt Editor) allows `no-repeat` to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon (`;`) after your `background: url("background_image.jpg")`

If you miss a semicolon after an element, nothing after it until the end of the `{}` will work.

A semicolon **is not** needed however, on single-style elements or on the last style like the following examples:

`.class { color: red }`

```
.class {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red
}
```

Basically, a semicolon is required after every style, up until the last style. Although removing the semicolon from the last style is not recommended since you (or other contributors to the code) may forget about this when adding more styles to the element later on.